# struts 2 property tag equivalent in spring 3 mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tags

is there any equivalent tag for struts2 property tag in spring mvc ? i am displaying the value returned from java class method call on jsp.

Eg.

```
<s:property value="%{a.getabc()}" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

To invoke the getter for `abc` property of your `a` instance you can simply use this SpEL expression in your JSP:

```
${ a.abc }
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<c:out value="${ a.abc }" />
```